# fundamental group of a sphere with 2 handles

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Prove that the fundamental group of a sphere with 2 handles contains a free group of 2 generators.

Intuitively, it is clear that we can cut a figure homotopically equivalent to a bouquet of two spheres with a plane, but I do not know how to formalize this and whether it follows that the free group of 2 generators is contained in the fundamental group of the pretzel.

Comment: You can do this purely algebraically: The space you describe is an (the) orientable surface of genus 2, computing the fundamental group of which may be a good exercise :)

Comment: Your 2nd sentence is simply wrong. How much algebraic topology do you know? Do you know the covering theory and van Kampen theorem? Do you know the combinatorial group theory (Freihensatz)? And please remove the "general topology" tag, it is inappropriate.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I know van Kampen theorem and covering theory

Comment: The easiest way is to show that the eight figure "$\infty$" is a retract of that space, and therefore inclusion induces monomorphism on fundamental groups.

Comment: @freakish this is what they are saying in their post, if you replace "spheres" with "circles" (which I think is an honest typo). They want to formalise it.

Comment: @FShrike no, "homotopically equivalent" is by far not the same as "retract". The eight figure **is not** homotopically equivalent to the space.

Comment: and making that distinction would be a first step on the road to formalisation...  but "cut a figure" suggests to me they have some good idea about it

Comment: I'm not sure how "cutting" is related to retraction. Anyway constructing a retraction is not hard. You first embed the space in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that it is symmetric along $XY$ plane. The first step is to reflect upper piece onto the lower. The next step is to shrink sides until we hit the eight figure. That's what I can give as an answer, but I won't give concrete formulas, its too much hassle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant "bouquet of two circles". Even if, the space is not homotopy equivalent to it.

The way we are going to do this is by the following:

> **Lemma.** Let $X$ be a space and $A\subseteq X$ its retract. Then $\pi_1(A)$ embeds into $\pi_1(X)$.

*Proof.* Let $r:X\to A$ be retraction and $i:A\to X$ inclusion. Then by functoriality of $\pi_1$ we have $$id=\pi_1(id)=\pi_1(r\circ i)=\pi_1(r)\circ\pi_1(i)$$

and therefore $\pi_1(r)$ is surjective while $\pi_1(i)$ is injective. $\Box$

So it is enough to find a retract of our space with $\mathbb{F}_2$ as fundamental group. The obvious choice is bouquet of two circles, a.k.a. the eight shape. But we have to be careful. Not every eight shape on this surface will be its retract.

Have a look at this (horrible yet useful) drawing:

[image]

which is a 2d section of our space. The first step of constructing our retraction is by projecting entire upper half onto the lower. The blue arrows indicate that.

So we endup with half sphere with two half handles. The second step is to get rid of handles like this:

[image]

So we shrink/deform handles into the surface, and we end up with half sphere with two holes in it. If we flatten it then we get this:

[image]

Finally we can draw our eight shape around those holes:

[image]

with blue arrows indicating retraction. The rest follows from our lemma.

This of course is not truely formal solution, but putting concrete formulas is a tedious job, which I will leave to you. :)